# Path al ejecutar python desde Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo descargado **Python 3.10** desde la tienda de Microsoft.

Al momento de ejecutar un script de `python` desde la terminal inicio desde la ruta y ejecuto el script. Al realizar un `os.getcwd()` me da la ruta desde la cual estoy ejecutando el programa. *Hasta aquí todo correcto*.

El problema se encuentra cuando le hago doble click al archivo `.py` y al ejecutar un `os.getcwd()` me muestra la carpeta `C:\Windows\System32\`.

Habrá forma de hacer que al hacer doble click en el archivo `.py` se inicie en la carpeta en la cual estoy haciendo doble click.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que realicé y me funcionó fue crear un batch que llame a

> python archivo.py

Así toma la ruta de donde se ejecuta como el path principal.

Comment: Tambien estoy aprendiendo python y lo que hago es hacerlo como lo aconsejan en los videotutoriales desde una ventana de comandos, para hacerlo desde el explorador de windows, deberías, botón derecho sobre un archivo .py, Abrir con.. Elegir otra aplicación, y buscar el ejecutable de python, para asociarlo, al igual que se hacen con cualquier .doc, .jpg, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Habría que aclarar algunas cosas.

El directorio de trabajo (*CWD*) es sólo eso, un sitio desde donde ejecuta python.

Cuando python tiene que buscar un script, hay varias rutas que va probando hasta dar con él. Simplificando bastante, se puede decir que va buscando en las rutas definidas por `sys.path`, cuya primera entrada será el primer sitio que va a buscar.

Cuando entras por línea de comandos, la primera entrada del `sys.path` es el directorio de trabajo (representado por una cadena vacía `''`). Por eso es fácil importar los ficheros python que hay en el directorio desde donde haya ejecutado python.

Si en cambio entras ejecutando un script, ya sea por haciendo click o como argumento de entrada, la ruta al fichero aparece como primera entrada del `sys.path`. Esto facilita que el script pueda encontrar el resto de scripts que le acompaña.

Algunos scripts alteran la primera entrada de `sys.path` para asegurar que siempre apunte al directorio del script en ejecución. Para ello usan una variable global llamada `__file__` que indica la ruta del script que se está ejecutando. Personalmente, no aconsejo alterar las rutas de búsqueda si no se tiene claro lo que se está haciendo, podría alterar el funcionamiento del resto de módulos.

Sería algo así:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path

if "__file__" in globals():
    sys.path.insert(0, str(Path(__file__).parent))
```